# Copy rows and paste at the end of another sheet

Tags: vba

I want to copy rows 3 and below from Sheet2 and paste at the end of Sheet1. Rows in Sheet2 have different lengths. Not sure if I am selecting row3 and then row4, 5, etc. until end of sheet2.

My code so far. I am getting errors:

```
Sub Macro5()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
        .Cell("A", 3).EntireRow.Select
        Do Until LastRow
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Paste
        Loop
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Should I set a range from row3 - lastrow and loop through range?

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy from row 3 till the end of Sheet 2 using the following code:

```
Public Sub copy_rows()

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.count
Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows("3:" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for this code.

```
Sub copy()
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = 3 To Lastrow
        Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(i).copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```